# Regular expression in unzip files argument not working

Tags: regular-expression, zip, posix

I'm trying to view the contents of a zip archive using an extremely simple regular expression. This works:

```
rmorton@Rockette:~$ unzip -l Downloads/WeiDU-Linux-236.zip "*/i386/tolower" "*/i386/weidu" "*/i386/weinstall"
Archive:  Downloads/WeiDU-Linux-236.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   135308  2013-11-17 21:48   WeiDU-Linux/bin/i386/tolower
   774816  2013-11-17 21:47   WeiDU-Linux/bin/i386/weidu
   130392  2013-11-17 21:48   WeiDU-Linux/bin/i386/weinstall
---------                     -------
  1040516                     3 files
```

But this does not:

```
rmorton@Rockette:~$ unzip -l Downloads/WeiDU-Linux-236.zip "*/i386/(tolower|weidu|weinstall)"
Archive:  Downloads/WeiDU-Linux-236.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
---------                     -------
        0                     0 files
```

What gives? Do I have a misunderstanding of how regular expressions work on the command line, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thats not regular expression.

Comment: I understand this must seem like a stupid question to someone with more experience. But what's the point of a site like this if I can't ask novice questions without being downvoted? I read man unzip several times and didn't realize it didn't support the full range of pattern symbols used by most command line utilities. Again, it was a novice mistake. But should it be downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @DisplayName I didn't assume you did :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) of unzip. It doesn't talk about regular expressions, just about the two special characters * and ?.

Comment: These are often called wildcards or globbing characters (though the latter is more shell-related).

Comment: In my opinion the man page uses confusing language -- if you read it (link above), you see it *does* talk about regular expressions: `Regular expressions (wildcards) may be used to match multiple members`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-LL` option for forcing conversion of every filename to lowercase, regardless of the originating file system

Comment: How does this relate to the question being asked?